# Ext JS datepicker, get a date range from two different calendars

Tags: javascript, extjs, datepicker

Good day all, I'm entering in a big EXT JS project and unluckily I'm totally nood in Ext js, I'm trying to learn as much as possible from tuts and examples, but I'm struck on this basic problem.

I have two different datepickers defined as follow:

```
items: {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        layout: 'hbox',                    
                        items: [{
                            title: 'FROM',
                            margin: '5',
                            items: {
                                xtype: 'datepicker',
                                start: true,
                                reference: 'startDate',
                                maxDate: new Date(),
                                maxText: 'Future dates are not available',
                                bind: {
                                    value: '{startDate}'
                                },
                                showToday: false,
                                listeners: {
                                    select: 'checkDateInterval'
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            title: 'TO',
                            margin: '5',
                            items: {
                                xtype: 'datepicker',
                                start: false,
                                reference: 'endDate',
                                bind: {
                                    value: '{endDate}'
                                },
                                maxDate: new Date(),
                                showToday: false,
                                listeners: {
                                    select: 'checkDateInterval'
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
```

I've succefully defined the controller, where I have done a simple "console.log()" of everything the datepicker passed me:

```
Ext.define('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxxxxxSetupController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.investmentsetupcontroller',
    checkDateInterval: function (data){
        console.log("data: ", data);
    }
});
```

and that is working as expected.
The only issue is that I received a whole object full of data in the console.log, and I imagine that there should be a easier way to get the two selected dates. May I ask you some advice to handle this? my goal is to get those two dates, makes some calculations and call another function with the data.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I prepared fiddler for you. Check this and if you want same then fine or modify as you want will and let me know then will get the value for both the date for your calculation

Comment: To get those to date use `data.value`

Comment: well, it was very simple in the end, thanks so much for lead me there!

Comment: Did that work ?

Comment: yes, using data.value I get the value and using data.reference, I can get the reference used in the view (so I can know which date is the one in data.value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you need use `data.value`
your code will be like

```
checkDateInterval: function (data){
       console.log("data: ", data.value);
}
```

Also check the fiddle here. [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1h9e)